# Image doesn't show up as my background in Android

Tags: android, xml, image, background

I've added this attribute to my XML.

```
  android:background="@drawable/background"
```

"@drawable/background" refers to the file background.psd which is located in the drawable folder.

The background does not appear when i run it (in the emulator).

What am i missing?

Comment: Why don't you change the format of your image from psd to png??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use psd files as drawables. Try saving it as png.

Comment: Is there any solution except for transforming the psd file ?

Thank you.

Comment: Transforming? I think you have to save it as png, there is no other way to solve this.

Comment: @WinstonLiu he's right. .psd files are too heavy as they keep all the layers and metadata.

Comment: @royiby Not only that, but they're not supported.